# Print image and record audio input

Tags: python, image, audio, record, intervals

I am very green about programming but wish to learn and develop.

I want to write a simple application that will be useful in linguistic treatments - but at first it is simple demo.

The application is about to display image and record sound during projection.
There are few variables - interval and image/sound/movie clip paths - taken from external txt file (for the beginning - later I would like to perform some creator with presaved configurations).

The config file now looks like:

```
10
path1
path2
...
```

The first line is about to input interval in seconds, next there are paths to images, sounds or movie clips (I tried with images for now).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# main.py

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np

import pyaudio
import wave

import time

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import multiprocessing

import threading
from threading import Thread

master = Tk()

conf_file = open("conf.txt", "r")   #open conf file read only
conf_lines = conf_file.readlines()  
conf_file.close()

interwal = conf_lines[0]            #interval value from conf.txt file
bodziec1 = conf_lines[1]            #paths to stimulus file (img / audio / video)
bodziec2 = conf_lines[2]
bodziec3 = conf_lines[3]

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = interwal           #every stimulus has it's own audio record file for further work

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")    #filename is set to year / month / day - hour / minute / second for easier systematization

def nagrywanie():                               #recording action - found somewhere in the all-knowing web
    p = pyaudio.PyAudo()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* nagrywanie")                                   #info about record to start

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    print("* koniec nagrywania")                            #info about record to end

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(timestr, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

def bod1():                                                 #stimulus 1st to display / play
    image = Image.open(bodziec1)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

def bod2():
    image = Image.open(bodziec2)                            #stimulus 2nd to display / play
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

def bod3():
    image = Image.open(bodziec3)                            #stimulus 3rd to display / play
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

def odpal():                                                #attemption to run display and recording at the same time
    Thread(target = bod1).start()
    Thread(target = nagrywanie).start()

    # Wait interwal for odpal                               #give impetus for time in first line of the conf.txt
    time.sleep(interwal)

    # Terminate odpal                                       #stop giving impetus
    bod1.terminate()

    # Cleanup                                               #?? this part is also copied from all-knowing internet
    p.join()

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=odpal)                #wanted the program to be easier for non-programmers to operate so few buttons are necessary
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

When asked few programmers about the code it is as simple as riding a bike, so I wanted to learn how to write it by myself.

I guess it is peace of cake for professionals - 1000s of thanks to these ones who want even to read this junk.

It takes a lot of time for me to understand and figure out the exact commends that is why I am asking politely about the help - not only for education but also for better diagnosis.

Excuse me for the language - English is not my native language.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the code?

Comment: 1. The image is not printed on the screen.

Comment: I defined the actions and want to run them simultaneously. How can I define the action like: def start_test(): show image for interwal seconds, record sound for interwal seconds, stop show, stop record, save audio file as date-time.wav - I can write the same block for every stimulus, but if could be written better - waiting for suggestions. Sorry for comment above - first time using this forum.